# I have several records in SQL Server 2012 that were opened after original record was opened

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to merge the data but not all information is the same.

This is an example of the type of data:

```
clientid    nameid   first_name last_name   Guest_Status    Guest_Number
------------------------------------------------------------------------
126         SJONES01     SALLY  JONES           ACTIVE          541
126         AJONES0      AMELIA JONES           INACTIVE        883
312         ASMITH00     APRIL  SMITH           ACTIVE          872
0           ASNITH00     APRIL  SMITH           ACTIVE          925
```

In both cases, I only need the first record as someone opened a new file with similar or slightly
different information. I need a way to merge the records into one as that is all that is needed and
have the other one deleted. The first and second examples have different names because the person
uses their middle name and the third and fourth were just opened without checking if one was already opened. I have several of both kinds of records.

Comment: Decide what logic to use to determine if records should be merged, and then implement the logic in UPDATE and DELETE statements.  We can't tell you what logic to use to decide if a record is a duplicate or not.  It has to come from your business rules.

Comment: The problem here is which is the 'correct' clientid/Guest_Number/etc? I don't see how we can help here with the information given? I would also like to mention use of a Single Naming convention, (either camelCase, all_with_underscore or Like_This. Please stop doing a pin-n-mix of naming styles

Comment: The first record listed is an example of what is correct. I can't enter exact information this was a model.  I didn't create the tables I am just having to use them.